# Oracle client support for VAX OpenVMS 7.3

Tags: oracle, clients, openvms, vax

Does Oracle support any kind of client and  C/C++ pre compiler for VAX OpenVMS 7.3 to connect to a Oracle server? On oracle.com they only have clients for Alpha and Itanium. I am using a simh VAX. And I have a Oracle 11g express database.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to locate some seriously old Oracle distribution.

Oracle release 7.3.4 is the highest Oracle release supported on VAX;

Oracle releases 9.2 and later do not support connecting with Oracle7. 
Oracle 7.3.4 may or might not connect to 11G express. I doubt it.
For sure anything above 9i was never supported. See Metalink ( 207303.1 ?)

Here is a public place which has a snapshot of the support matrix: http://oracleappstechnology.blogspot.com/2008/09/placeholder_08.html

You can only stretch that vax so far...

Cheers,
Hein